# Regular expression Dreamweaver array to object

Tags: php, arrays, regex, replace, dreamweaver

I need to find and replace my php code using Dreamweaver in `array` to `object` form like

**Find in code**

```
$row['keyval']
```

**Replace with**

```
$row->keyval
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match this using

```
(\$.*?)\['(.*?)'\]
```

which will put both relevant parts in two capturing groups, see [this Example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7cvQZZ/1)

I don't know Dreamweaver, but given the ability to replace using Capturing groups, your replacement should look sth. like

```
$1->$2
```